# Is it a standard that the width or height of a "display:none" element is zero?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

The offsetWidth or offsetHeight of a "display:none" element is 0 on Chrome.

What I want to know is this is standard behavior defined by W3C, or just a dialect of browsers? Or it is a de facto supported by all modern browsers?

I searched out the web and found almost no text addressing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is standard behaviour.

If `display` is `none`, then no layout box is created:

> Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; it creates no box at all. CSS includes mechanisms that enable an element to generate boxes in the formatting structure that affect formatting but are not visible themselves. Please consult the section on visibility for details.
>
> https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/visuren.html#display-prop

And if there is no box, then it returns zero:

> The offsetWidth attribute must return the result of running these steps:
>
> 1. If the element does not have any associated CSS layout box return zero and terminate this algorithm.
> 2. Return the border edge width of the first CSS layout box associated with the element, ignoring any transforms that apply to the element and its ancestors.
>
> https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetwidth

Comment: thank you very much. I also found this on MDN: 

"If the element is hidden (for example, by setting style.display on the element or one of its ancestors to "none"), then 0 is returned."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth